# Refresh when navigating back to component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I open a second component to add some records and when I save, I navigate back to the original component.  The problem is that the newly created records do not display on the original component.  The odd thing is that the `doInit` function does not fire when I navigate back.

Therefore, my assumption is that the first component never closes when I navigate to the second component to create the records.

I'm trying to either close the first component out when I navigate to the second or refresh the first when I go back. How can I do that?

Here is the code on the second component to save record and navigate back to first component.

```
    insertGS : function(component, groupstructures, callback) {

        //call apex to save the newly created group structures
        var action = component.get("c.saveGroupStructure");
            action.setParams({gs: groupstructures
            });

  $A.enqueueAction(action);

  ///This part of code is used to navigate back to the GroupStructuresList Component
        //variable to hold the account id for my naviagation back to original component
        var recordId = component.get("v.existinggroupstructure.Account__c")
        //set urlEvent Variable to navigate back to the original component
         var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        urlEvent.setParams({
            "url" : "lightning/n/Group_Structures_List?//Aid=" + recordId + "&Tid=123456789"    
        });
        ///navigate back to groupstructures page
        urlEvent.fire();


        },
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

window.location = "lightning/n/Group_Structures_List?//Aid=" + recordId + "&Tid=123456789";

instead of the urlEvent? Or is there any reason not to use that? My team and I built a heavily customized community and used that command to switch pages.

All the best,
tiruman

Comment: Thanks for responding @tiruman   I had tried that before but I am ending up with the following url:  https://horizonblue--lightning.my.salesforce.com/one/lightning/n/Group_Structures_List?//Aid=001q000000nv4YTAAY&Tid=123456789  I need:  https://horizonblue--lightning.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/Group_Structures_List?//Aid=001q000000nv4YT&//Tid=123456789

Comment: I think window.location has been disabled in the current version.  Seems like I read that somewhere.

Comment: I also read that window.location is not the ideal future solution.

Comment: Found it. [When in Lightning Experience your page doesn’t have a window.location to set!](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_visualforce/lex_dev_visualforce_navigation)

Comment: That's amazing: Instead of answering your question, it is I who learned something. Thanks a lot! =)

Comment: Ha!  I appreciate the effort Tiruman!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure where you require a redirect but it seems like timing is the issue.  I would try moving your redirect code into an `action.setCallback()` function.  Or maybe you can write your redirect into the Renderer part of the second component that displays (assuming you get there).

Comment: Thanks lxalmida.  I think you might be onto something.  I had once or twice where the refresh worked so what your saying makes sense.  I will try you approach.  thanks!